# How to unfollow a deleted question.

Tags: support, follow-post

I have just noticed I am following a question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3643049/399263), although I might have clicked *follow* unintentionally because I never usually follow questions.

Anyway, this question is now deleted so I would like to clear it from my follow list, however when I click the unfollow button I get a popup with this text:

**This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on**

And the post is not removed from my follow list.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: [The same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346423/how-do-i-unfollow-a-deleted-question) on the main meta was marked (status-review).

Comment: Thank you, I searched terms unfollow/deleted but found no duplicate, I forgot it could be general and answered in main. So apparently this is a bug...

Comment: @zwim I noticed the same issue and wrote this fairly detailed [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349292/562482) . As with the other meta question that YuiTo Cheng mentioned, it has also been marked status-review (by Adam Lear).

Comment: Evidently we can un-bookmark on the left of that profile list, and unfollow on the right. No need to visit the post. I think before it was just favorites, now it is split into bookmarks and follows